# Run multiple call in a for each loop at the same time PHP?

Tags: php, foreach

I call a function in a for each loop in my PHP code like that :

```
foreach ($tests as $test) {
        $mytest = new Test;
        $maintest = $mytest->Test_function($mytest);

        $testarray[$test] = $mytest->getTest();
        }
```

Each call of $mytest->Test_function() could take about 2 mins (calls to remote servers and test on fetched data).

If I have 5 elements in my $tests array, the time spend by the script is : ~= 5 * 2 mins
I know PHP is not a asynchronous language but do you know a way to launch at the same time all 5 calls ?

It's very frustrating too wait about 10 mins the and of my script ^^

Comment: I don't know this service, I'll laybe try it, isn't it too hard to learn ?

Comment: Check curl_multi_exec & curl_multi_select. Post some example code of your "Test_function", maybe we can help you refactore the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a part of code of Test_function($mytest) :

```
try {
            $ch = curl_init();

            if (FALSE === $ch)
                throw new Exception('failed to initialize');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $mytest);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 2);
            $agents = array(
                'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1',
                'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1.9) Gecko/20100508 SeaMonkey/2.0.4',
                'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; en-US)',
                'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7; da-dk) AppleWebKit/533.21.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.5 Safari/533.21.1'

            );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agents[array_rand($agents)]);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

            $html = curl_exec($ch);

            if (FALSE === $html)
                throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));

        } catch(Exception $e) {

            trigger_error(sprintf(
                'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',$mytest,
                $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),
                E_USER_ERROR);

        }
        curl_close($ch);
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        @$dom->loadHTML($html);

        $linklist= array();

        foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
            $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
            array_push($linklist, $href);
        }
```